# Issue understanding how to read and process data in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, matrix, neural-network, recommendation-engine

I have been trying to understand how to feed a model on tensorflow but I have been having little to no success on the matter , I am building a recommendation system (I don't have any code since I have been trying lots of things and I can't make it work) , and this is the description of it:

I have a matrix of 0's and 1's, each row is an user , each column is an item , each 1 represents that the user owns the item and a 0 represents that the user does not own the item, my idea is to introduce this data on the neural network so I determine items that can be related to a certain user (output a vector of 1's and 0's) .

Previous to this I run a "filter" because I have to get rid of users or items that are too expensive or users that are too unsatisfied with their purchases . I am not versed on tensorflow however I do understand ML , but of course I am having trouble enconding and decoding the data I really don't know what to do right now, can anybody help me?

Comment: It's really difficult to help without any code. Try to include some reproducibe code which exemplifies your problem.

Comment: I understand what you mean , however my issue is with encoding the matrix (and therefore decoding the output) which means I am stuck at the begining of the algorithm I haven't created the layers for example

Comment: Still you need to provide code. In tensorflow you can construct several types of neural networks, e.g. multiperceptron neural networks, recurrent neural networks, LSTM neural networks... Which one do you have in mind? Depending on how you're planning to train your neural network, you might need to reshape your data, for exampe you can train in batches of some specified size. Your question is too broad and you need to narrow it more to get some help

Comment: "I have been trying lots of things and I can't make it work". Those are the things that you need to provide together with simplified and reproducible code.

Comment: I see I was thinking on using a regular multilayered network to start since it is the simplest (I guess) , and the training would be that I expect certain 0's and 1's to some users and that can define similarity between users and the recommendation

For example if I have this user 11001 and this user 10011 they are fairly similar since they both have the 1st item and the last item, and they both don't have the 3rd item , as I filtred I know they are satisfied , so when I run a recommendation for the second user it should deploy something like 11011 so 2nd item is recommended

Comment: Ill take some extra time to build something that can actually be executed, will post when I have done it thanks :)!

Comment: Try to make your example as reproducible as possible. Even with your explanation I don't see an obvious dataset of the form `(x_i,y_i)`. The input layer is `x_i` and the output layer is `y_i` (which I assume should be 0 or 1), in your case `x_i` would be something like `(1,0,0,1,1)` (the input layer has 5 neurons) but this setting sounds a bit strange to me.

Comment: If you build something then it makes it a lot easier to help